# Why is my WTelegramClient not sending reply inline markup with message?

Tags: c#, wtelegramclient

Can't send ReplyInlineMarkup in message with WTelegramClient

Really can't understand why this is not working

```
var keyboardButton = new KeyboardButtonUrl { text = "Go", url = "https://asd.com" };
var keyboardButtonRow = new KeyboardButtonRow() { buttons = new KeyboardButton[] { keyboardButton } };
var rim = new ReplyInlineMarkup() { rows = new KeyboardButtonRow[] { keyboardButtonRow } };

var asd = await telegram.Messages_SendMessage(target, "asd", Helpers.RandomLong(), null, rim);
```

I expect a message with text asd to be sent and under it a keyboard in line button with text "Go" but only the message with text and appear.

[image: Message sent:]

Comment: user accounts cant do that, its only for bots